# Combining two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

If I have a table set up like so:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>user_login</td>
    <td>user_pass</td>
    <td>user_nicename</td>
    <td>user_email</td>
    <td>user_url</td>
    <td>user_registered</td>
    <td>user_activation_key</td>
    <td>user_status</td>
    <td>display_name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1
    <td>user123</td>
    <td>pass123</td>
    <td>Tom J.</td>
    <td>email@email.com</td>
    <td>2015-09-09 04:17:29</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Tom Jones</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And another table set up like so:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>umeta_id</td>
<td>user_id</td>
<td>meta_key</td>
<td>meta_value</td>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
<td>nickname</td>
<td>T Jones</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>first_name</td>
<td>Tom</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>last_name</td>
<td>Jones</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>description</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>rich_editing</td>
<td>true</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Is there a good way to combine both tables so that the meta values for all matching users (user_id = ID) fall under a single column. If I try doing a JOIN on table a to table b it splits all the data into separate rows. I would like all the new data to fit on a single row so it's easier to access. To note: I am unable to alter the table structure here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are _HTML_ tables, not SQL tables.  Are you trying to combine these HTML tables?

Comment: @Dave Rottino:  Do you understand the difference between HTML and SQL and between HTML tables and SQL tables? Your question talks about SQL tables but your code is HTML tables.

Comment: Please add your desired result to clarify the question.

Comment: The HTML table output is for presentational purposes only. The issue is table 2 has values that match the user in table 1 split up 1 per line. I'd like to combine the two tables so the meta values turn into columns of the first table. Ultimately I need to output as a .csv with each user and data on one row.

Answer (score 0):

Use these Query for solution

```
select u.*,(select group_concat(meta_value) from user_tag where user_id = u.ID) as meta_value_user from user as u where ID = 1;
```